# Video of Anand vs Kasparov from 1996

Tags: kasparov, anand, chess-videos

Where can I find a video of Anand vs Kasparov played at 1996 Las Palmas. There is a mention of it in this [ChessBase article](https://en.chessbase.com/post/a-history-of-cheating-in-chess-4):

> At this point Kasparov went into a deep think. Jan Timman started to
> speculate whether White couldn’t play the very forceful 20.g4.
> Kasparov’s second Yury Dokhoian immediately confirmed: “That’s what
> he’s looking at!” Yury understands Kasparov’s thinking better than
> anyone else in the world.
>
> Meanwhile White had played 20.Bd5. The game lasted six hours, Anand
> defended very tenaciously and at around 10 p.m., much to the
> disappointment of Kasparov, a draw was agreed.
>
> When he left the stage Garry came into the press room, spotted me and
> walked straight over. “I couldn't win it, could I, Fred?” he asked,
> with a troubled look on his face. It was a bit shocking: the world
> champion and best player of all times consulting a chess amateur,
> asking for an evaluation of the game he has just spent six hours on!
>
> Naturally Garry wasn't asking me, he was asking Fritz. He knew I would
> have been following the game with the computer. “Yes, you had a win,
> Garry. With 20.g4!” My answer vexed him deeply. “But I saw that! It
> didn't work. How does it work? Show me.” I could not dictate all the
> lines, but then Yury walked over. Garry and Anand listened in horror
> while he gave them all the critical lines. All of this was captured on
> video and published in ChessBase Magazine 56

Also, from the same article:

> Yury Dokhoian checking the 20.g4 line with Fritz in real time during
> the game, Kasparov and Anand analyse after six hours of play [video
> grabs from the CBM 56 multimedia report].

This implies that there is definitely a video of this somewhere, but I was unable to find it.

Answer (score 3):

This video was recorded by Chessbase and released with their Magazine 56 (stated here https://en.chessbase.com/post/remembering-yury).

So I guess you have to get your hands on this magazine for the video. You can try to contact Chessbase, maybe they will give you a link to the video, as it is quite old now.